# RestTemplate DELETE throws HttpClientErrorException: 405 Method no Allowed

Tags: java, spring, httprequest, resttemplate

I am writing client app for https://api.ai service and use org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate for my HTTP requests.

The problem is that DELETE requests always return error 405,

```
private static final String URL_INTENTS = "https://api.api.ai/v1/intents?v={apiVersion}";

HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                    httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[]{MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}));
                    httpHeaders.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + speaktoitConfig.getDeveloperAccessToken());
                    httpHeaders.set("ocp-apim-subscription-key", speaktoitConfig.getSubscriptionKey());
                    resp = restTemplate.exchange(
                            URL_INTENTS, HttpMethod.DELETE, new HttpEntity<String>(intentId, httpHeaders),
                            AiVocabulariesResponse.class, speaktoitConfig.getApiVersion()).getBody();
```

but PUT and GET requests works fine.

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[]{MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}));
        httpHeaders.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + speaktoitConfig.getDeveloperAccessToken());
        httpHeaders.set("ocp-apim-subscription-key", speaktoitConfig.getSubscriptionKey());
        resp = restTemplate.exchange(
                URL_INTENTS, HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<String>(JsonMapper.MAPPER.writeValueAsString(aiQueryIntentsList), httpHeaders),
                AiVocabulariesResponse.class, speaktoitConfig.getApiVersion());
```

I am pretty sure api.ai to support DELETE, because it is written in their docs
https://docs.api.ai/docs/intents

In your opinion is there a problem with my code, or I should write to the api.ai service support?

Here is a full test code

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import junit.framework.Assert;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;


    public class TestDeleteRequest {

        @Test
        public void test1DeleteRequest() {
            Assert.assertTrue(testDeleteRequest());
        }

        public static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

        static boolean testDeleteRequest() {

            final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            final String URL_INTENTS = "https://console.api.ai/v1/intents?v={apiVersion}";
            final String API_VERSION = "20150901";

            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[]{MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}));
            httpHeaders.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + "fc361168a9434289b7457408fa0acdd8");
            httpHeaders.set("ocp-apim-subscription-key", "76dba252-3e56-488d-9350-22f32b3b55f0");
    //download all elements headers
            String respStr = null;
            try {
                respStr = restTemplate.exchange(
                        URL_INTENTS, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<String>("", httpHeaders),
                        String.class, API_VERSION).getBody();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                return false;
            }
//parse elements ids
            List<String> intentIds = new LinkedList<>();
            try {
                int cnt = 1;
                JsonNode rootNode = MAPPER.readTree(respStr);
                Iterator<JsonNode> elements = rootNode.elements();
                while (elements.hasNext()) {
                    JsonNode aiIntentNode = elements.next();
                    JsonNode aiIntentIdNode = aiIntentNode.path("id");
                    String aiIntentId = aiIntentIdNode.asText();
                    intentIds.add(aiIntentId);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                return false;
            }

            if (intentIds.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
//try to delete the first one
            try {
                restTemplate.exchange(
                        URL_INTENTS, HttpMethod.DELETE, new HttpEntity<String>(intentIds.get(0), httpHeaders),
                        String.class, API_VERSION).getBody();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                return false; //TODO catch HttpClientErrorException 405 Method no Allowed
            }

            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you shwo your full delete controller and also the request you sent.

Comment: If you look at the examples provided in this link, https://docs.api.ai/docs/intents, `DELETE` method example has url as `/intent/` which is very strange as all the other method and its examples were defined as `/intents/`. Even the `DELETE` method's Heading is defined as `/intents/{iid}`, but in the example it's only given as `/intent/`. Try replacing `/intents/` with `/intent/` in your `DELETE` request..

Answer (score 0):

The `URL_INTENTS` value appears to be incorrect: Based on the docs you referenced above, you should be hitting the URL `/intents/{intent-id}`. However, based on your value of `https://api.api.ai/v1/intents?v={apiVersion}` you aren't specifying the ID of the intent to delete. Thus, when the server finds the root `/intents` resource, it is simply forbidding you to delete that root resource.